# se puede localizar los ids de campos con puppeteer?

Tags: dom, puppeteer, input-type

quiero automatizar la bajada de un fichero de una pagina con pupeeteer, ya lo he hecho con otras y mas o menos se como hacerlo, pero en esta en concreto tiene una pega para hacer el login pues el id de usuario y contraseña se calculan aleatoriamente cada vez que se llama a la pagina
(https://newtelematics.northgateplc.es) alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?
Gracias

Comment: He probado eso pero el name de usuario y password es el mismo que el id y se cambia cada vez que se accede a la pagina. seguire investigando. Gracias temylogin

Answer (score 1):

Yo localizaría estes elementos como `form[name=login] input[type=text]` y `form[name=login] input[type=password]`

Comment: lo probare de imediato y te dire que tal, mil gracias